# Adjacency matrix is not returning all digraph connections

Tags: python, networkx

My objective is to build a code that, given an adjacency matrix, return me a digraph.
I wrote this snippet:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> import numpy as np
>>> G = nx.DiGraph()
>>> arr = np.array([[1,1],[1,0]])
>>> G = nx.from_numpy_array(arr)
>>> list(G.nodes)
    [0, 1]
>>> list(G.edges)
    [(0, 0), (0, 1)]
```

I was expecting that the last command would return me:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)]
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces what you want:

```py
arr = np.array([[1,1],[1,0]])
G = nx.from_numpy_array(arr, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
list(G.nodes) # [0, 1]
list(G.edges) # [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)]
```